# Agregar "www" al dominio raíz sin afectar al sub-dominio, sin perder SSL

Tags: azure, dominio

Como puedo agregar `www` solo al dominio raíz?

Estoy usando `Azure WebSites`. Este es mi código:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

y

```
<rule name="Rewrite Subdomain To Directory" enabled="true">
  <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.dominio\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido, una URL con `www.dominio.com` y `dominio.com` son diferentes y en términos de certificados SSL deberías de contratar dos. Para evitar este problema, tendrías que elegir un dominio como predeterminado y redireccionar el otro, para que siempre se realice el acceso desde el dominio elegido.

Puedes hacerlo desde el panel DNS de tu proveedor de dominios, y a mi parecer es la solución más elegante.

Comment: Tengo todo configurado, es decir; mi SSL funciona sin y con "www". Lo que busco es siempre colocar el "wwww" cuando alguien escriba "dominio.com" mandarlo a: https://wwww.dominio..com y no a https://dominio..com

Comment: En la Zona DNS de tu dominio, tendrás un registro principal de tipo `A`: 
`dominio.com. 0 A 176.31.184.172`

Y tienes que añadir un registro `CNAME` (de tipo redirección) para que el www.dominio.com apunte a dominio.com :
`www.dominio.com. 0 CNAME dominio.com.`

Comment: Entiendo, ahora que lo veo... mi sitio web tarda unos segundos mas en establecer una "conexión segura" consideras que mi código esta bien?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas que tu certificado este creado con SNI. Esto solo funcionará para navegadores nuevos.

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/iis8-sni-browser-support.htm

En Azure en el apartado de sal binding cuando seleccionas el certificado puedes activar ssl SNI y veras los dominios que hayas ingresado en el certificado.

https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm